# How to deal with statsmodel.api OLS efficiency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, statistics, pandas-groupby, statsmodels

I have a `df` consist of columns: `industry`, `comp_id`, `year`, `y` and `x1, x2, x3, ..`. The data looks like this:

```
   indus  comp_id  year      y   x1    x2     x3  other_var
0      A      100  2000   90.0    9  44.0   95.0         66
1      A      100  2001   59.0   65   4.0   63.0         52
2      A      100  2002   75.0   49  29.0   64.0         27
3      A      100  2003   83.0   29  86.0   48.0         57
4      A      100  2004   82.0   64  43.0   67.0         58
5      A      100  2005   88.0   30  54.0   75.0         29
6      A      100  2006   91.0    3  46.0  100.0         68
7      A      101  2005    NaN   65  53.0  100.0         57
8      A      101  2006   83.0   56  67.0   60.0         40
9      A      101  2006  112.0  100  97.0   59.0         54
10     A      101  2007   53.0   95   NaN    3.0         55
11     A      101  2007  113.0   28  77.0   96.0         30
12     A      101  2008   84.0    2  79.0   57.0         54
13     A      101  2008   53.0   19  12.0    NaN         62
14     B      102  2002   83.0   92  88.0   31.0         31
15     B      102  2003  102.0    7  67.0   96.0         28
16     B      103  2003    NaN   49   NaN   72.0         22
17     B      103  2004    NaN   60   NaN   52.0         69
18     B      103  2005    NaN   74   NaN   44.0         49
19     B      103  2006    NaN   21   NaN   31.0         38
20     B      103  2007    NaN   69   NaN   36.0         28
21     B      103  2008    NaN    5   NaN    6.0         32
22     B      103  2009    NaN   22   NaN   10.0         61
```

I need to run a regression by group of company over year and return the new column with residual. My code is:

```
def func_reg_err(df, yvar, xvar, alpha=True):
    y = df[yvar].copy()
    x = pd.DataFrame(df[xvar].copy())
    if alpha == True:
        x['intercept'] = 1.
    mod = sm.OLS(y,x, missing='drop')
    res = mod.fit()
    err = y - mod.predict(res.params, x)
    return err
```

To run regression by group, I use the following code:

```
df['residual'] = df.groupby('comp_id', group_keys=False).apply(func_reg_err, 'y', ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], False)
```

If the data is nice then nothing happens, the code work smoothly. However, in my `df`, there are many companies with `Missing` data (entire of a column) or companies with too few observation (only 1 or 2). In the sample, they are companies with `comp_id = 102, 1003`. One has only 2 observations, and the other has too many missing value. Those group of companies make my code keep returning error.

I could work around by create a copy of `df`, then manually filter those disqualify companies, run `func_reg_err` and then `merge` back with `df` again. However, I see this method is just a work around solution. I am looking for an efficiency way to deal with this.

What I want is for those groups that are not qualified, the column `residual` will return with `np.Nan`

Comment: please post sample data and point to the error. Hard to guess how your data will look like

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan: sorry, I just update with a sample data. Please have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a minimum acceptable sample length (either as a total or for one/all regressor columns) at your helper function, for instance:

```
def func_reg_err(df, yvar, xvar, alpha=True, min_samples=30):
    # Return NaNs only
    if len(df) < min_samples or (df.notnull().sum(1) < min_samples).any():
        return pd.Series(index=df.index)

    # Carry on with your regression
    y = df[yvar].copy()
    x = pd.DataFrame(df[xvar].copy())
    if alpha == True:
        x['intercept'] = 1.
    mod = sm.OLS(y,x, missing='drop')
    res = mod.fit()
    err = y - mod.predict(res.params, x)

    return err
```

Comment: But what about the groups of companies with full np.NaN for oen/many column?

Comment: I've added a little snippet. Just count the NaNs for each column and compare that to the same `min_samples` parameter.

Comment: Actually count the number of non-NaNs and compare that against your threshold. I've edited it.